# HTML - Why is frameset not showing up?

Tags: html, doctype, frameset

Please check the js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7f304y52/
The framesets are not working though correct Doctype is put, why? Can you explain what happens when incorrect doctypes are put, will the page crash or that element is discarded

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<span>asdfsdf</span>

<frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
<frame src="http://www.w3schools.com/">
</frameset>
<button>asfasf</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set correct DTD in Fiddle Options and delete your own `head` tag.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this, in Google Chrome seems to work and in fiddle set correct DTD.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

  <frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
    <frame src="http://www.w3schools.com/">
    <frame src="http://www.google.com/">
    <frame src="http://www.facebook.com/">
  </frameset>

</html>
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
```

or

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: frameset and frame are not supported in HTML5

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use iframe instead -

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/"></iframe>
```

Comment: If you need using more frame, better used `<frameset>`.

Comment: Thanks for the iframe suggestion, but my question is my question, why are framesets not showing up